# R dplyr join by range or virtual column

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to join two tibbles by a range or a virtual column. but it seems the `by` - parameter just allow to handle `chr` oder `vector(chr)` of existing column names.

In my example I have a tibble `d` with a column `value`, and a tibble `r` with a `from` and a `to` column.

```
d <- tibble(value = seq(1,6, by = 0.2))
r <- tibble(from = seq(1,6), to = c(seq(2,6),Inf), class = LETTERS[seq(1,6)])

> d
# A tibble: 26 x 1
   value
   <dbl>
 1   1.0
 2   1.2
 3   1.4
 4   1.6
 5   1.8
 6   2.0
 7   2.2
 8   2.4
 9   2.6
10   2.8
# ... with 16 more rows

> r
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   from    to class
  <int> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     2     A
2     2     3     B
3     3     4     C
4     4     5     D
5     5     6     E
6     6   Inf     F
```

now I want to join the `value` column in `d` within the range of `from` and `to` in `r`:

```
d %>% inner_join(r, by = "value between from and to")     # >= and <
```

I can't find a way to do this so decided to join the `floor` of `value` in `d` with the `from` column in `r`

```
d %>% inner_join(r, by = c("floor(value)" = "from"))
```

of course i can create a second column to solve that:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(join_value = floor(value)) %>% 
  inner_join(r, by = c("join_value" = "from")) %>% 
  select(value, class)

# A tibble: 26 x 2
   value class
   <dbl> <chr>
 1   1.0     A
 2   1.2     A
 3   1.4     A
 4   1.6     A
 5   1.8     A
 6   2.0     B
 7   2.2     B
 8   2.4     B
 9   2.6     B
10   2.8     B
# ... with 16 more rows
```

but isn't there a more comfortable way?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Super interesting thread - just a minor comment -  as far as I can see, no accepted answer yet, although many good answers, incl. your own?

Answer (score 14):

I don't think inequality joins is implemented in `dplyr` yet, or it ever will (see this discussion on [Join on inequality constraints](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/557)), but this is a good situation to use an SQL join:

```
library(tibble)
library(sqldf)

as.tibble(sqldf("select d.value, r.class from d
                join r on d.value >= r.'from' and 
                          d.value < r.'to'"))
```

Alternatively, if you want to integrate the join into your `dplyr` chain, you can use `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

d %>%
  fuzzy_join(r, by = c("value" = "from", "value" = "to"), 
             match_fun = list(`>=`, `<`)) %>%
  select(value, class)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 31 x 2
   value class
   <dbl> <chr>
 1   1.0     A
 2   1.2     A
 3   1.4     A
 4   1.6     A
 5   1.8     A
 6   2.0     A
 7   2.0     B
 8   2.2     B
 9   2.4     B
10   2.6     B
# ... with 21 more rows
```

Notice I added single quotes around `from` and `to` since those are reserved words for the SQL language.

Comment: Elegant solution.  I needed to replace the ">=", "<" with single backticks match_fun = list(`>=`, `<`)) in order for the match_fun to work.  Kept getting a logical argument error, in any case, a good solution to categorizing by ranges.

Comment: @JamesCrumpler Yes, functions with non-standard names have to be surrounded by backticks.

Answer (score 10):

Ok thanks for advices, this was pretty interesting. I finally wrote a function `range_join` (inspired by @ycw's code) and compared all described solution in view of runtime.

I like fuzzy_join but with only 50k rows in `d` it needs more than 40sec. Thats too slow.

Here the result with 5k rows in `d`

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(sqldf)

#join by range by @WiWeber
range_join <- function(x, y, value, left, right){
  x_result <- tibble()
  for (y_ in split(y, 1:nrow(y)))
    x_result <-  x_result %>% bind_rows(x[x[[value]] >= y_[[left]] & x[[value]] < y_[[right]],] %>% cbind(y_))
  return(x_result)
}

#dynamic join by @ycw
dynamic_join <- function(d, r){
  d$type <- NA_character_
  for (r_ in split(r, r$type))
    d <- d %>% mutate(type = ifelse(value >= r_$from & value < r_$to, r_$type, type))
  return(d)
}

d <- tibble(value = seq(1,6, by = 0.001), join = TRUE)
r <- tibble(from = seq(1,6), to = c(seq(2,6),Inf), type = LETTERS[seq(1,6)], join = TRUE)

# @useR sqldf - fast and intuitive but extra library with horrible code
start <- Sys.time()
d2 <- tbl_df(sqldf("select d.value, r.type from d
                join r on d.value >= r.'from' and 
                d.value < r.'to'"))
Sys.time() - start

# @useR fuzzy_join .... very cool but veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery slow
start <- Sys.time()
d2 <- d %>%
  fuzzy_join(r, by = c("value" = "from", "value" = "to"), match_fun = list(`>=`, `<`)) %>%
  select(value, type)
Sys.time() - start


# @jonathande4 cut pretty fast
start <- Sys.time()
d2 <- d
d2$type <- cut(d$value, unique(c(r$from, r$to)), r$type, right = FALSE)
Sys.time() - start

# @WiWeber floor
start <- Sys.time()
d2 <- d %>% 
  mutate(join_value = floor(value)) %>% 
  inner_join(r, by = c("join_value" = "from")) %>% 
  select(value, type)
Sys.time() - start

#  @WiWeber cross join - filter
start <- Sys.time()
d2 <- d %>%
  inner_join(r, by = "join") %>% 
  filter(value >= from, value < to) %>%
  select(value, type)
Sys.time() - start

# @hardik-gupta sapply
start <- Sys.time()
d2 <- d %>%
  mutate(
    type = unlist(sapply(value, function (x) r[which(x >= r$from & x < r$to), "type"]))
  ) %>% 
  select(value, type)
Sys.time() - start

# @ycw re-dynamic join
start <- Sys.time()
d2 <- d %>% dynamic_join(r)
Sys.time() - start

# @WiWeber range_join
start <- Sys.time()
d2 <- d %>% 
  range_join(r, "value", "from", "to") %>%
  select(value, type)
Sys.time() - start
```

Results:

```
# @useR sqldf - fast and intuitive but extra library with horrible code
Time difference of 0.06221986 secs

# @useR fuzzy_join .... very cool but veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery slow
Time difference of 4.765595 secs

# @jonathande4 cut pretty fast
Time difference of 0.004637003 secs

# @WiWeber floor
Time difference of 0.02223396 secs

# @WiWeber cross join - filter
Time difference of 0.0201931 secs

# @hardik-gupta sapply
Time difference of 5.166633 secs

# @ycw dynamic join
Time difference of 0.03124094 secs

# @WiWeber range_join
Time difference of 0.02691698 secs
```

greez WiWeber

Comment: Thanks for sharing your function and comparing the results. I learned a lot! You got my upvote.

Comment: `range_join <- function(x, y, value, left, right){
  x_result <- tibble()
  for (y_ in split(y, 1:nrow(y))){
    d_ <- x[x[[value]] >= y_[[left]] & x[[value]] < y_[[right]],]
    if(nrow(d_) > 0)
      x_result <-  x_result %>% bind_rows(d_ %>% cbind(y_))
  }
  return(x_result)
}`

Comment: range_join gives an error if there are no records that fall between range. I've made an update on separate comment

Answer (score 3):

You use the cut function to create a "class" in object d and then use a left join.

```
d <- tibble(value = seq(1,6, by = 0.2))
r <- tibble(from = seq(1,6), to = c(seq(2,6),Inf), class = LETTERS[seq(1,6)])

d[["class"]] <- cut(d[["value"]], c(0,2,3,4,5,6,Inf), c('A',"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), right = FALSE)
d <- left_join(d, r)
```

To get the right buckets, you just need to work with the cut function to get what you want.

Comment: `d$class <- cut(d$value, unique(c(r$from, r$to)), r$class, right = FALSE)`

I like that, the only disadvantage: its acting like a `left_join`, so I have to remove data from d which are out of range ( less 1)
But thanks that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate` and `case_when` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

d2 <- d %>%
  mutate(class = case_when(
    value >= 1 & value < 2 ~ "A",
    value >= 2 & value < 3 ~ "B",
    value >= 3 & value < 4 ~ "C",
    value >= 4 & value < 5 ~ "D",
    value >= 5 & value < 6 ~ "E",
    value >= 6             ~ "F"
  ))
d2
# A tibble: 26 x 2
   value class
   <dbl> <chr>
 1   1.0     A
 2   1.2     A
 3   1.4     A
 4   1.6     A
 5   1.8     A
 6   2.0     B
 7   2.2     B
 8   2.4     B
 9   2.6     B
10   2.8     B
# ... with 16 more rows
```

**Update**

Here is a workaround by defining a function for this task.

```
d <- tibble(value = seq(1,6, by = 0.2))
r <- tibble(from = seq(1,6), to = c(seq(2,6),Inf), class = LETTERS[seq(1,6)])

library(dplyr)

# Define a function for dynamic join
dynamic_join <- function(d, r){

  if (!("class" %in% colnames(d))){
    d[["class"]] <- NA_character_
  }

  d <- d %>%
    mutate(class = ifelse(value >= r$from & value < r$to, r$class, class))
  return(d)
}

re_dynamic_join <- function(d, r){
  r_list <- split(r, r$class)
  for (i in 1:length(r_list)){
    d <- dynamic_join(d, r_list[[i]])
  }
  return(d)
}

# Apply the function
d2 <- d %>% re_dynamic_join(r)
d2
# A tibble: 26 x 2
   value class
   <dbl> <chr>
 1   1.0     A
 2   1.2     A
 3   1.4     A
 4   1.6     A
 5   1.8     A
 6   2.0     B
 7   2.2     B
 8   2.4     B
 9   2.6     B
10   2.8     B
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Comment: the problem is, the example is pretty simple i need it for dynamic range tibble

Comment: I agree with @WiWeber, while this works for the specific example, it is not very practical as you will have to change the cases everytime the `r` table is modified, not to mention how tedious it will be to add more cases manually.

Comment: @WiWeber Please see my update. This is a workaround by creating a function `re_dynamic_join`. This will perform the join task and be part of the pipe operation. `dplyr` is the only package needed for this solution.

Comment: @ycw I used your solutions and compared them in a answer above. thanks

Comment: @useR I used your solutions and compared them in a answer above. thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` for this

```
library(tibble)

d <- tibble(value = seq(1,6, by = 0.2))
r <- tibble(from = seq(1,6), to = c(seq(2,6),Inf), class = LETTERS[seq(1,6)])
d <- cbind(d, data.frame(class = (unlist(sapply(d$value, function (x) r[which(x >= r$from & x < r$to), "class"]))) ) )

d
   value class
1    1.0     A
2    1.2     A
3    1.4     A
4    1.6     A
5    1.8     A
6    2.0     B
7    2.2     B
8    2.4     B
9    2.6     B
10   2.8     B
11   3.0     C
12   3.2     C
13   3.4     C
14   3.6     C
15   3.8     C
16   4.0     D
17   4.2     D
18   4.4     D
19   4.6     D
20   4.8     D
21   5.0     E
22   5.2     E
23   5.4     E
24   5.6     E
25   5.8     E
26   6.0     F
```

Answer (score 1):

I really liked @WiWeber's range_join function, but it gives an error if a record is not within range. Here's a modification

```
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(value = c(seq(1,4, by = 0.2),9))
r <- tibble(from = seq(1,5), to = c(seq(2,5),8), class = LETTERS[seq(1,5)])


range_join <- function(x, y, value, left, right){
all_matches <- tibble()
x = as.data.frame(x)
y = as.data.frame(y)
x$index=x[,value]
for (i in 1:nrow(y)){
    matches = x %>% filter(index>=y[i,left] & index<= y[i,right])
    if (nrow(matches)>0){
        all_matches = all_matches %>% bind_rows(matches %>% cbind(y[i,]))
    }
}
all_matches = all_matches %>% select(-index)
return(all_matches)
}


data <- d %>% 
range_join(r, "value", "from", "to")

data
```