# If statements and Dates

Tags: r, date, if-statement

What I am trying to achieve is allocate a new column with a variable that changes over time.
It is just one of them that is changing so what I would like to do is After (date) put 40 instead if 22

I currently have this Code that is not working properly

```
Idea:
    if(lst$taskDate <= as.Date("2018-11-18")){
    t2$Budget <- case_when(
        t2$taskStaffName == "L" ~ 20,
        t2$taskStaffName == "J" ~ 22,
        TRUE ~ 40
    )
    }else{
        if(lst$taskDate >= as.Date("2018-11-19"))
    t2$Budget <- case_when(
        t2$taskStaffName == "L" ~ 20,
        t2$taskStaffName == "J" ~ 40,
                TRUE ~ 40

    )
        }


This is the Data Sample:

# A tibble: 3,692 x 4
   taskStaffName taskDate   taskMinutes taskBillable
   <chr>         <date>     <chr>       <chr>       
 1 G             2018-07-02 300         true        
 2 G             2018-07-02 180         true        
 3 L             2018-07-02 300         true        
 4 L             2018-07-02 180         false       
 5 C             2018-07-02 360         false       
 6 C             2018-07-02 120         false       
 7 G             2018-07-03 480         true        
 8 L             2018-07-03 30          true        
 9 L             2018-07-03 180         true        
10 L             2018-07-02 30          true        
# ... with 3,682 more rows



Desired Outcome:

# A tibble: 3,692 x 5
   taskStaffName taskDate   taskMinutes taskBillable Budget
   <chr>         <date>     <chr>       <chr>         <dbl>
 1 J             2018-07-02 300         true             22
 2 J             2018-07-02 180         true             22
 3 L             2018-07-02 300         true             20
 4 L             2018-07-02 180         false            20
 5 C             2018-07-02 360         false            40
 6 C             2018-07-02 120         false            40
 7 L             2018-07-03 480         true             20
 8 L             2018-07-03 30          true             20
 9 J             2018-11-19 180         true             40
10 J             2018-11-19 30          true             40
# ... with 3,682 more rows
```

Comment: I don't get why you're trying to combine `if` with `case_when`. Why not just do one `case_when`:  `case_when(t2$taskStaffName == "L" ~ 20,
        t2$taskStaffName == "J" & lst$taskDate <= as.Date("2018-11-18") ~ 22,
                TRUE ~ 40)` If you really want to nest, nest `case_when` inside `case_when`. Or use `ifelse`. `if()` isn't vectorized, it will only check the top row if you give it a whole column.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know my mistake.
Still learning so, this are just ideas that came up to my mind and I appreciate any constructive criticism, is all along the way of learning R. Thanks though.

If you can give me a bit more details of how I could get this done I will appreciate that.

Comment: I think i was pretty detailed. I just didn't write `lst$Budget =` in front of my code. Here it is with that little addition: `lst$Budget = case_when(t2$taskStaffName == "L" ~ 20, t2$taskStaffName == "J" & lst$taskDate <= as.Date("2018-11-18") ~ 22, TRUE ~ 40)` should do it as far as I can tell. I'll test it if you share the data in a copy/pasteable way (e.g., with `dput()`.) Though now that I look at it I'm confused about your data - you only show one input data frame, but you use `t2` and `lst` as if you have two data frames - I have no idea which is which...

Comment: The code works. However what is doing is changing all the budgets after that date to 40 instead of just J as I need. do you know how I can fix this ?

Comment: The `TRUE ~ ...` determines what happens when no condition from above is met. I just copied `TRUE ~ 40` from your code - I thought that's what you want. If you want the budget numbers unmodified in this case, do `TRUE ~ lst$Budget`.

Comment: What I am trying to say is J before this date was 20 after this date is 40 all the rest keep it on 40 ( except for l that is 20)

Comment: I work it out, Thank you so much Gregor

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I got it up and running with this bit of coding lst2$Budget <- case_when(
    lst$taskStaffName == "L"  ~ 20,
    lst$taskStaffName == "J" & lst$taskDate < as.Date("2018-11-18") ~ 22,
    lst$taskStaffName == "J" & lst$taskDate > as.Date("2018-11-18") ~ 40,
    TRUE ~ 40
)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gregor have mentioned I just used case_when for this problem.

I end it up using this code:

```
lst2$Budget <- case_when(
    lst$taskStaffName == "L"  ~ 20,
    lst$taskStaffName == "J" & lst$taskDate <= as.Date("2018-11-18") ~ 22,
    lst$taskStaffName == "J" & lst$taskDate > as.Date("2018-11-18") ~ 40,
    TRUE ~ 40
)
```

thank you all for taking some time out and trying to solve my question!

Answer (score 1):

I *infer* from this that you will have different before/after rates for each `taskStaffName`, so it might be better to rethink how you approach the problem. Instead of doing a `case_when` (or worse, `ifelse`) including every combination of name and date, merge in a frame of before/after rates and use the appropriate field.

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
   taskStaffName taskDate   taskMinutes taskBillable
 1 G             2018-07-02 300         true        
 2 G             2018-07-02 180         true        
 3 L             2018-07-02 300         true        
 4 L             2018-07-02 180         false       
 5 C             2018-07-02 360         false       
 6 C             2018-07-02 120         false       
 7 G             2018-07-03 480         true        
 8 L             2018-07-03 30          true        
 9 L             2018-07-03 180         true        
10 L             2018-07-02 30          true        ")
x$taskDate <- as.Date(x$taskDate)

library(dplyr)
# library(tibble)
taskRates <- tibble::tribble(
  ~taskStaffName, ~before, ~after
 ,"J"           ,      22,     40
 ,"L"           ,      20,     20
 ,"G"           ,      20,     41
 ,"C"           ,      40,     41
)

cutoffDate <- as.Date("2018-11-18")
x %>%
  left_join(taskRates, by = "taskStaffName") %>%
  mutate(Budget = if_else(taskDate <= cutoffDate, before, after)) %>%
  select(-before, -after)
#    taskStaffName   taskDate taskMinutes taskBillable Budget
# 1              G 2018-07-02         300         true     20
# 2              G 2018-07-02         180         true     20
# 3              L 2018-07-02         300         true     20
# 4              L 2018-07-02         180        false     20
# 5              C 2018-07-02         360        false     40
# 6              C 2018-07-02         120        false     40
# 7              G 2018-07-03         480         true     20
# 8              L 2018-07-03          30         true     20
# 9              L 2018-07-03         180         true     20
# 10             L 2018-07-02          30         true     20
```

This hard-supposes a single interesting cutoff date. If you are planning on having a multi-month *schedule* of rates, then this problem should probably be revisited, since you might be better off with a conditional join (e.g., range-join, fuzzy-join). Refs:

- [R dplyr join by range or virtual column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46795636/3358272)
- https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881

---

**Edit**

If your logic is never going to be more complex than 1 user changing on a date, then you can use the `case_when` logic as @Gregor previously recommended:

```
x %>%
  mutate(
    Budget = case_when(
      taskStaffName == "L"     ~ 20,
      taskStaffName == "J" &
        taskDate <= cutoffDate ~ 20,
      TRUE                     ~ 40
    )
  )
#    taskStaffName   taskDate taskMinutes taskBillable Budget
# 1              G 2018-07-02         300         true     40
# 2              G 2018-07-02         180         true     40
# 3              L 2018-07-02         300         true     20
# 4              L 2018-07-02         180        false     20
# 5              C 2018-07-02         360        false     40
# 6              C 2018-07-02         120        false     40
# 7              G 2018-07-03         480         true     40
# 8              L 2018-07-03          30         true     20
# 9              L 2018-07-03         180         true     20
# 10             L 2018-07-02          30         true     20
```

Comment: There are many names that is almost a waste of time going one by one, do you have any trick to change just L 20 J 40 and the rest 40 ?

Comment: You need to be more specific. It sounds like you have only one special case, L=20, everything else 40, but I'm not certain based on adding this to your original question.

Comment: so, L is 20 J is 20 all the rest is 40. but after that date J change to 40 the rest keep stay as they were

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got it done with the bit of coding down bellow. However, I appreciate your time!