# How do you find if a number is between a range of multiple mins and max numbers

Tags: r

In R I have:

DataSet1

```
A 
1
4
13
19
22
```

DataSet2

```
  (min)B    (max)C
     4          6
     8          9
     12        15
     16        18
```

I am looking to set up a binary column D based on whether A is between B and C.

So D would added to dataset 1 and calculated as follows:

```
A  D
1  0
4  1
13 1
19 0 
22 0
```

I have tried using the InRange function but it just calculating for between one row of B and C rather than all intervals.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs5qL.png)

Comment: The usual way to check if `num` is in `(min, max]` is: `num > min & num <= max`. If you use `&`, it is vectorised so you can work with columns directly.

Comment: `D <- ifelse(A >= B & A <= C, 1,0)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R dplyr join by range or virtual column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795636/r-dplyr-join-by-range-or-virtual-column)

Comment: @A.Suliman not the best target, this is a simple `ifelse`, no need for joins.

Comment: @zx8754 I don't think OP has this simple dataset in the original dataset, but maybe I over complicate the question. Let's wait and see if he's going to accept the above suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated the question as is a longer vector A. The code above works but only if the vectors are the same length.

Comment: When I try to calculate D I get the error "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length". If A were the same length as B and C then I do not get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `fuzzy_left_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% fuzzy_left_join(df2, by = c("A" = "B", "A" = "C"), 
                             match_fun = list(`>=`, `<`)) %>% 
        mutate(D = ifelse(is.na(B) & is.na(C), 0, 1))

   A  B  C D
1  1 NA NA 0
2  4  4  6 1
3 13 12 15 1
4 19 NA NA 0
5 22 NA NA 0
```

Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 4L, 13L, 19L, 22L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
df2 <- structure(list(B = c(4L, 8L, 12L, 16L), C = c(6L, 9L, 15L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Would it be possible to extend the interval? i.e., `A >= B-20` and `A < C+5`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `sapply` from base R -

```
df1$D <- sapply(df1$A, function(x) {
  +any(x >= df2$B & x <= df2$C)
})

df1

   A D
1  1 0
2  4 1
3 13 1
4 19 0
5 22 0
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for the help. I used Shree's solution in the end, very tidy.

Comment: @Gary Happy to help. Consider marking it correct using the tick mark at top left.