# Merge two data frames based on range value in R

Tags: r, join, merge

Would it be possible to have a function that would consider having a range in the "by" argument of a joint?

Example:

```
#Table 1
  A B C D
1 a 1 10 15
2 a 11 1000 12.5
3 b 1 5 2
4 b 6 1000 1

#Table 2
  A B
1 a 53
2 b 3
```

Joint Table:

```
  A B 1.D
1 a 53 12.5
2 b 3 2
```

Comment: I don't entirely follow the logic you're using, but the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46795636/5325862) might help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to update table 2 based on a rolling join with table 1 on A and B

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tb1)
setDT(tb2)

tb2[tb1, on = .(A, B), roll = -Inf, D := i.D]
```

This updates `tb2` so now we have

```
tb2
#    A  B    D
# 1: a 53 12.5
# 2: b  3  2.0
```

Data used:

```
tb1 <- fread('
A B C D
 a 1 10 15
 a 11 1000 12.5
 b 1 5 2
 b 6 1000 1
')

tb2 <- fread('
  A B
 a 53
 b 3 
')
```